# What's the point of the 60W Apple MagSafe replacement charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

One of the cable tabs on my MagSafe charger for my MacBook came undone, so I took this as a sign to retire the charger to home use and to purchase another for travel. When I went to my local Best Buy, they had two chargers for sale, 60W and 85W, that looked the same size, sold for the same price, etc. The only difference was that the 85W supported the MacBook Pro, while the 60W only supported the MacBook.

Even though I am a MacBook owner, I figured I might, sometime in the future, purchase a MacBook Pro and I went with the 85W charger. When I opened it up I found it was slightly larger than the 60W charger it was replacing, but for all intents and purposes there's no real difference between the two. So why does Apple sell a 60W replacement (or even manufacture the 60W at all)? Are there enough people that want to save 25W?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most switching power supplies are most efficient when operating at 50% capacity. And they're definitely pretty inefficient at less than 20% capacity.

Since the MacBook draws less power than a MacBook Pro, I would suspect that an 85w power supply would work just fine, but the larger power supply for the MBP probably would draw more power from the wall socket than is necessary when connected to a MB because it is operating in a suboptimal capacity range.

Here's an example: Take for example the 45w power supply for the MacBook Air. Sure you could hook up the 85w power supply, but since the MBA might only draw 20 watts, the power supply is operating at less than 25% capacity. At this capacity, the power supply may only be 60% efficient (an educated guess), that means the power supply has to draw 33 watts of AC power just to supply the laptop with 20 watts of DC power.

**Long story, short:** It's a power conversion efficiency thing. I'd say buy the one that is designed for your laptop so that you save energy.

Comment: I suspected this, which is one of the reasons why I like that I'm leaving my 60W at home and using my new 85W on the road.

Comment: @Ranger: The efficiency figures you made up are not necessarily accurate; it depends on the design of the specific power supply and the load under various conditions (e.g., whether the laptop is charging or fully-charged). The larger power supply may actually be more efficient, based on Kyle's typical usage scenario. (see http://www.motherboards.org/articles/guides/1487_7.html for a simple counterexample) @Kyle: I'd suggest using a Kill a Watt meter to test each power supply's power draw yourself under different loads. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @Rob: If you will take a look at the chart that you referenced, the range is from 100w to 550w. What the chart does NOT show is the efficiency from 0w to 100w. I suspect this was left out for a reason (to hide that the efficiency falls off sharply as the power draw goes from 100w down to 0w.) So your assertion that the larger power supply could be more efficient for a smaller laptop is probably wrong as the smaller laptop would never draw enough power to hit the efficiency sweet-spot of the larger power supply. I stand by my original assertion: Buy the one that is designed for your laptop.

Comment: @Ranger: To clarify, the article shows a power supply that still operates at almost peak efficiency at slightly less than 20% load, whereas you claimed that power supplies are "pretty inefficient at less than 20% capacity." You can speculate about the efficiency of any given power supply, but without actually measuring it, you're just shooting in the dark--especially since the load will vary depending on the user's habits. Given the same two laptop power supplies, one could be more efficient for my usage pattern while the other is more efficient for yours.

Comment: @Ranger: Also, I don't think the omission of the 0W-100W range was an attempt to "hide" anything. The author simply did not expect his target audience to be interested in power draws of less than 100W.

Comment: @Rob: Power supplies that are considered "efficient" are at a minimum 80% efficient (or more) in their conversion from 20% load up to 100% of their rated capacity. That one that you linked to doesn't even hit 80%. You're also comparing apples to oranges here. That ATX PSU that you linked to has more physical room to work with and active cooling. This thread is about Apple Laptop power bricks which don't have such a luxury in their design. From my experience w PSUs, I'm sure the power conversion efficiency curve is more dramatic than that graph that you cherry picked to support your argument.

Comment: And yes, I agree with you about the less than 20% load range not being "hiding". Most curves/charts don't include the efficiency for at least one of many reasons. (1) Testers are lazy and don't test below 20%. (2) Most well-designed devices that use a power supply don't use less than 20% load, so there is no sense in testing that load range. (3) If you DID test that load range (0% to 20%), it would show the steep drop off in efficiency which skews the graph and/or makes it harder to read. You can see the beginnings of it in that chart that you linked to: A sharp drop off to the left of 100w.

Comment: So again. You wouldn't use a 90w laptop power supply with a Netbook (which probably draws a max of 10w) because it is inefficient. Possibly as low as 50%, depending on the maker of the power supply.

Can you use a larger laptop power supply with a smaller laptop? Sure, but why spend the extra money for the larger one? why drag around the heavier power supply? and why get worse power conversion (waste more energy?)

In this case, only if you also had BOTH the larger and smaller Apple laptop and wanted the ability to use the power supply with either would it make any sense...

Comment: @Ranger: As you've pointed out, you lose efficiency when the load is below a certain threshold. But you also lose efficiency when the load is above a certain threshold, which is why the larger power supply may be more efficient during charging and the smaller supply may be more efficient when the battery is not charging. But that's only part of the equation. Miniaturization does not necessarily imply more efficient power conversion. By trying to cram components into smaller physical dimensions, the manufacturer may have had to sacrifice some power conversion efficiency.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I had both 65W and 90W chargers for my old Dell laptop, and the 90W charger was noticeably faster at charging the laptop. So, to answer all your other questions, the larger power supply may be worth the extra money and weight if you're usually on-the-go and run off the battery, and need the quickest recharge time. And, as I've already mentioned, the 90W supply may also be more efficient if you're like many people, and you only plug in to recharge. But without measuring the difference, we cannot reasonably conclude which supply is more efficient.

Comment: @Rob: At this point, I am not sure what you're arguing anymore. I think we're basically making the same point, except that you're talking about exceptions to the rule. (for the record, I never said anything about miniaturization being more efficient some how. In fact, I said that a larger ATX PSU would probably be more efficient than a power brick because it has the luxury of having more room and active cooling, but this is sort of irrelevant at this point...) And btw, the name is Pretzel. I just happen to be a Ranger.  :-)

Comment: Regarding the 65w vs. 90w psu issue you bring up, it sounds like the laptop you have is supposed to use a 90w psu. If you gave it a 500w psu, it wouldn't charge any faster, but a 65w psu definitely charges slower because the psu cannot supply as much current as the laptop demands. Since Apple engineers are smart folks, I would surmise that the 85w psu (designed for MBP) would not charge a MB any faster than the 60w model (designed for MB) And you can probably use a 60w psu with the MBP, but you'd probably limit the charge rate. And you're right, we cannot know for sure without actually testing

Comment: @Pretzel: My original point was twofold: first, without measuring the efficiency of both chargers you can't just claim one is more efficient than the other, as you did in your answer. Second, each one will have different efficiencies under varying loads, and these loads are directly related to a given person's typical usage pattern. I guess I was hoping that, rather than speculating on which charger is more efficient (the original question), you would update your answer to acknowledge that there is no way to know which PSU is more efficient without actually measuring both under varying loads.

Comment: Moving on, my laptop shipped with a 65W power supply, although I could have opted for the larger one when I bought it. Just as you have 14-hour, 6-hour, and 1-hour chargers for rechargeable AA batteries, you can use varying-wattage PSUs for laptops, as long as the PSU meets the minimum requirements for charging. If you use a higher-wattage PSU, you can charge the battery faster, but at some point you will see diminishing returns. It wouldn't make sense for Apple to specifically design their products to counteract this advantage.

Comment: @Rob: I generally disagree with you that it cannot be claimed that one is more efficient than another. A certain power supply that ships with a laptop should be properly engineered for it. I'm not saying that there are not exceptions. You seem to have found one, but it's Dell, I'm not surprised. Apple and IBM (now Lenovo) seem to engineer to higher standards. But seeing as you asked nicely, I'll edit my entry to note the caveat that it's possible that a larger power supply would serve a few people better. Although, in the case of an Apple laptop, this is highly unlikely.

Comment: As for your 1/6/14 hour AA analogy, again: "apples and oranges". If you buy a 1-hour AA battery charger and it comes with a 12v/2-amp (24-watt) power supply, buying a 12v / 4-amp (48-watt) power supply is NOT going to allow your AA's to charge any faster. The charger itself has an internal limit on how much current it will draw -- The same goes for laptops. At a certain point, the charge controller just won't charge the laptop battery any faster. It's not a "diminishing return", it's a hard limit. In your case, it looks like the Dell screwed you by shipping you a 65-watt (undersized) PSU.

Comment: @Ranger: Your last couple comments smack of fanboyism, which I suppose explains why you seem to think that your suppositions count as hard proof that the power supply that ships with a laptop is the ideal power supply in all respects (cost, weight, aesthetics, efficiency, reliability, etc.). The real world, unfortunately, is not so perfect, and compromises were likely made which adversely affected one or more of the power supply's characteristics under various loads.

Comment: In any case, I think you're misunderstanding something at a very fundamental level, or maybe you're just missing the obvious point. There's a contact on my Dell's power connector that allows the PSU to identify itself, which in turn allows the charging circuit in the laptop to increase the charging current when the 90W power supply is hooked up. You can charge a battery faster by increasing the charging current (a point I've been trying to make but you seem to keep missing).

Comment: So either the larger PSU will charge a Macbook faster, or Apple cut corners on their design. My money is on faster charging--although I do know Apple has, in the past, disabled or omitted features in their lower-end laptops for the purpose of market segmentation. With that, I bid thee adieu.

Comment: @Rob: Wow. I try to play nice and you call me a fanboi. (ouch.) Yes, I'm aware of the ability of a PSU made for modern laptops to communicate with the laptop. Yes, I understand more than well enough how voltage/current work. (probably more than you, as you haven't been able to solidly refute any of my points, yet I can poke holes in your flawed analogies all day.) The fact of the matter remains that the scenario that you've presented is an "edge case" (corner case.) The majority of users should still buy the power supply that was designed for their laptop and not a larger one. Ciao.

Comment: For anyone else who ever reads this stupid thread, I leave you with this: http://xkcd.com/386/  -- Very apropos...

Answer (score 5):

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=6301678

Sounds like it does work just fine.  You cannot use the smaller charger with MBP of course.  This is also the case with the MBA which uses a 45watt version.

In addition to what rangerpretzel said, which is the main technical reason:

But also, size matters to some, MBA users want portability. the 45 watt version is much smaller and the 60 is smaller then the 85.  Some people want the smallest one compatible with their computer.  Also, the original 85 watt magsafe power supply used to be even larger then it is today and was a concern at the time of release. Apple eventualy re-engineered it to the size it is now.

Cost wise, it might make more sence to just make one power supply, but apple does offer its users a "few" options. haha.

Comment: The MBA air is a different adaptor because of the angle the port is at which is a result of the case design. A MB or MBP adaptor just wouldn't fit and a MBA.  Even if it did fit would be underpowered for a MB and shockingly, probably dangerously, so for a MBP.

Comment: Oh, you kinda mis read what i meant. I just mean you "could" possibly use the larger power supplies with the smaller models, not the other way.

Comment: You never want to use an underpowered power supply, major fire danger there.

Comment: And yes, you are correct about the angled connector. If it was not angled, you could potentialy use a larger power supply, but its not recommended, needed, or efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely don't need to worry about your laptop being fried by the higher-capacity power adapter, because the laptop will only draw what it needs.

My 6-year-old laptop came with a 65W power supply. When I bought it, I could have gotten it with a 90W power supply, but I opted for the smaller power supply.  The docking station that I purchased later came with a 90W power supply which can also plug directly into the laptop.  I've noticed that the 90W supply charges the laptop faster, but I prefer it mainly because it has a much longer power cord.

The efficiency figures Ranger has hypothesized are not necessarily accurate; it depends on the design of the specific power supply and the optimal load range. A given power supply may be [more efficient](http://www.motherboards.org/articles/guides/1487_7.html) under your own typical usage scenario, but the only way to find out for certain is to [test each power supply's power draw yourself](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16882715001) under different loads.  For example:

- Plugged into the wall, but not into a laptop
- Laptop fully charged and turned on (idle)
- Laptop fully charged and maxing out power draw (e.g., transcoding video while burning a CD)
- Laptop charging but turned off
- Laptop charging and turned on (idle)
- Laptop charging and maxing out power draw (e.g., transcoding video while burning a CD)

You may find that the higher-wattage power supply is actually significantly more efficient under a high load than the lower-wattage power supply, because it is not near its maximum capacity.  In fact, you may find that the higher-wattage power supply is more efficient across the board, and the lower-wattage power supply only beats the bigger supply under a narrow range of loads. Or perhaps the smaller supply is *never* more efficient, and its only advantage is its smaller physical size.

Comment: I like where your head is at. I have a 60W MB adapter which has all but melted under the loads I frequently subject it to. Such as charging, compiling, and ripping a DVD (DVD read + video transcode) all at once.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the anecdotal evidence is that there are no problems, and this extends to a member of Apple Store staff who say they use MBP charger to charge all laptops and if you read the small print they are suitable for both MB and MBP.

I did find one person who said that their batteries "burnt out" while using the 85w charger with a MacBook but this seemed so far from the normal tale (that everything was fine, of which there are hundreds of accounts) that it may have been down to something else.

But it doesn't answer the question why do apple do it.  It would be simpler (certainly) and cheaper (probably - just down to bulk buying) to standardise.  The fact they haven't makes me think that there may be a reason, however it may be historic.  For instance it may be that the new MacBooks may run fine on either charger while the old ones don't.  To avoid having to specify model and year and risk selling someone a charger which will melt their old laptop, they may have just decided to stick with MacBook charger and a MacBook pro charger and avoid confusion.

The 60w adaptor incidentally is underpowered for the MBP - battery charging takes longer and it will get very very hot in extended use.  It works but really not advised.